# dismissViewControllerAnimated breaks GUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app i send a mail using MFMailComposeViewController.
This viewController is pushed with

```
 [self presentViewController:mailer animated:false completion:nil];
```

from an viewController that is on top of a uiNavigationController. When you're done mailing i remove the mfmailcomposeviewcontroller with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

The problem than is that my uinavigationController's view doesn't fill the whole screen and all the elements presented on the screen that are not part of this uinavigationcontroller become inactive. I have no Idea how to even begin to fix this so any hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: On the dismiss method, shouldnt `completion:` be `nil`, not `NULL`?

Comment: Is this an issue on an iPad or iPhone? If this is on the iPad, is a spit view controller being used?

Comment: If your `UINavigationController` does not take up the whole screen, that means you are displaying multiple view controllers? Do you have some kind of container view controller? Are you using controller containment methods to create proper VC hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the dismissViewController changes the size of the calling view. Having a transparent background on this view I didn't realize that... I could easily fix this problem by simply rescaling the view of the navigationcontroller again. I hope this answer will help anybody who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller that needs to present the `MFMailComposeViewController` is in a navigation controller then you should do it by calling :

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailer
                                        animated:YES
                                      completion:nil];
```

Then you dismiss it this way :

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewController:mailer
                                        animated:YES
                                      completion:nil];
```

Comment: ive tried both nil and null and I don't want it to be animated

Comment: It doesn't make such a difference to use null instead of nil as they're both 0 in their contexts. Read this http://nshipster.com/nil/
Does the answer behave as you want when you pass NO to animated ?

Comment: I did answer NO to animated the problem lies not with animation but with objects becoming inactive after the dismiss is called

Comment: It doesn't matter which view controller is presenting the `mailer` **if** you have properly created VC hierarchy.